# nest radio button selection - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, selection, event-listener

I am working on my personal site and I am trying to nest my radio buttons. 
I know I am supposed to have javascript running to do what I need it to do but I cant get a clear answer. What I am trying to do is as follows.

Options number 2 and 6 both have sub options to go with them. But I want that if i select 1 or 3-5 or 7 then the user cannot select any of the subs. and if the user selects a sub by mistake and tries to select one of the aforementioned numbers then it will clear the sub selection. please help. Or at lease can some one point me in the right direction? thanks so much.

```html
<div class="one">
<div class="two">
  <div class="three">
    <div class="four">
      <label class="five six">Section</label>
      <div class="seven">
        <label class="ten">
          <input value="option_1" name="radios" type="radio" />
          option 1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="seven">
        <label class="ten">
          <input value="option_2" name="radios" type="radio" />
          option 2</label>
        <br>
        <div class="one">
          <div class="one">
            <div class="two">
              <div class="three">
                <div class="four">
                  <div class="eight">
                    <label class="nine">
                      <input type="radio" name="inline radio" value="sub_1">
                      Sub 1</label>
                    <label class="nine">
                      <input type="radio" name="inline radio" value="sub_2">
                      Sub 2</label>
                    <label class="nine">
                      <input type="radio" name="inline radio" value="sub_3">
                      Sub 3</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="seven">
          <label class="ten">
            <input value="option_3" name="radios" type="radio" />
            option 3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="seven">
          <label class="ten">
            <input value="option_4" name="radios" type="radio" />
            option 4</label>
        </div>
        <div class="seven">
          <label class="ten">
            <input value="option_5" name="radios" type="radio" />
            option 5</label>
        </div>
        <div class="seven">
          <label class="ten">
            <input value="option_6" name="radios" type="radio" />
            option 6</label>
          <div class="one">
            <div class="two">
              <div class="three">
                <div class="four">
                  <div class="eight">
                    <label class="nine">
                      <input type="radio" name="inline radio" value="sub_1">
                      Sub 1</label>
                    <label class="nine">
                      <input type="radio" name="inline radio" value="sub_2">
                      Sub 2</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="seven">
          <label class="ten">
            <input value="option_7" name="radios" type="radio" />
            option 7</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little something using **Jquery** that might work if I understood your requirements correctly. The HTML is a dumbed down version of yours just to demonstrate the script.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("input[type=radio]").on("change",function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("two") || $(this).hasClass("six") || $(this).hasClass("sub"))
                $(".sub").removeAttr("disabled");
            else
                $(".sub").attr("checked",false).attr("disabled","disabled");

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type=radio name="lvl1" class="one" value=""> Option 1<br>
        <input type=radio name="lvl1" class="two" value=""> Option 2<br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=radio name="lvl2" class="sub two-sub" value=""> Sub 1<br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=radio name="lvl2" class="sub two-sub" value=""> Sub 2<br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=radio name="lvl2" class="sub two-sub" value=""> Sub 3<br>
        <input type=radio name="lvl1" class="three" value=""> Option 3<br>
        <input type=radio name="lvl1" class="four" value=""> Option 4<br>
        <input type=radio name="lvl1" class="five" value=""> Option 5<br>
        <input type=radio name="lvl1" class="six" value=""> Option 6<br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=radio name="lvl3" class="sub six-sub" value=""> Sub 1<br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=radio name="lvl3" class="sub six-sub" value=""> Sub 2<br>
        <input type=radio name="lvl1" class="seven" value=""> Option 7<br>
    </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the fiddle to check online: https://jsfiddle.net/bds87fjt/

The same solution as above using pure **Javascript**:-

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

    function disableSub(){
        sub = document.querySelectorAll(".sub");
        for(i=0; i<sub.length; i++){
        sub[i].checked=false;
        sub[i].disabled=true;
        }
    }
    function enableSub(){
        sub = document.querySelectorAll(".sub");
        for(i=0; i<sub.length; i++){
        sub[i].disabled=false;
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type=radio name="lvl1" onclick=disableSub(); class="one" value=""> Option 1<br>
        <input type=radio name="lvl1" onclick=enableSub(); class="two" value=""> Option 2<br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=radio name="lvl2" class="sub two-sub" value=""> Sub 1<br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=radio name="lvl2" class="sub two-sub" value=""> Sub 2<br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=radio name="lvl2" class="sub two-sub" value=""> Sub 3<br>
        <input type=radio name="lvl1" onclick=disableSub(); class="three" value=""> Option 3<br>
        <input type=radio name="lvl1" onclick=disableSub(); class="four" value=""> Option 4<br>
        <input type=radio name="lvl1" onclick=disableSub(); class="five" value=""> Option 5<br>
        <input type=radio name="lvl1" onclick=enableSub(); class="six" value=""> Option 6<br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=radio name="lvl3" class="sub six-sub" value=""> Sub 1<br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=radio name="lvl3" class="sub six-sub" value=""> Sub 2<br>
        <input type=radio name="lvl1" onclick=disableSub(); class="seven" value=""> Option 7<br>
    </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the fiddle for above: https://jsfiddle.net/0omtop0t/

And here's another neat little solution using just HTML and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/NhXUV/

Not sure, it'll work in your case though. Worth checking out.

Comment: yes this is exactly what I am looking for. The only problem is that since I am new at this I am trying to stay away from jquery. I do understand that they are like cousins. but im not ready to start working with that yet just javascript. But thank you so much for answering!

Comment: You're welcome :)
And if you're looking for a javascript free solution, you could check out that second fiddle I have listed. It uses HTML and CSS only.
BTW, if you like my answer and it works, would you mind selecting it as right answer and/or up-voting it, thanks ? :P

Comment: and I mean no Im not looking for a javascript free solution. I have no problem up rating anyones response :-)

Comment: Well, there you go....added same solution using pure Javascript. Hope it helps :)

Comment: You sir are a life saver

Comment: if I can ask ONE more thing. is there a way to have it so that if i select the sub box its top level automatically selects? but if you dont want to answer its more than fine youve been an immense help already!

Comment: that's definitely possible, but, since selecting any other option disables the subs for 2 and 6, how would the user select the subs? If you just want to clear the subs and not disable them on selecting options 1,3-5 and 7, then it might work. In that case, you can check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dfr5ceca/

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely go with JavaScript for this one.

Basically, you could write a function that would be called whenever a radio button from a `div` of the class, lets call it `gotNestedStuff`, has his selection changed. The toggle will show/hide the `div` with the class `nestedStuff` that contains the sub-options that can only be selected if the main option is.

Here's the basic function (with jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //let's hide the nested stuff on page load
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.nestedStuff').hide();
    });

    //on click on an element that has class "gotNestedStuff", show it's hidden content
    $('.gotNestedStuff .option').on('change', function(e) {
        console.log($(e.relatedTarget));
        $(e.target).parent('.gotNestedStuff').children('.nestedStuff').toggle();
    }); 
 </script>
```

Working with this HTML for example :

```
<div>
        <div class="optionContainer">
            <input class="option" type="radio" name="option" value="1">Option 1
        </div>
        <div class="optionContainer gotNestedStuff">
            <input class="option" type="radio" name="option" value="2">Option 2<br>
            <div class="optionContainer nestedStuff">
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="option" value="2.1">Option 2.1<br>
                <input class="option" type="radio" name="option" value="2.2">Option 2.2<br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="optionContainer">
            <input class="option" type="radio" name="option" value="3">Option 3<br>
        <div>
    </div>
```

You could also call a function "onclick" from your element that would validate if an item with nested stuff hidden is selected, that it should show it to the user.

Ex. `<input type="radio" onclick="myfunction()" />`